# Slow running code

Tags: c++, omnet++

I have the following function in my project:

```
void UDPBasicApp::incrementReceiveCounter(L3Address dest) {
    char numberOfDestNode[10];
    char name[50];
    strcpy(name,L3AddressResolver().findHostWithAddress(dest)->getFullPath().c_str());
    char temp[20];
    char *last = strrchr(name, '.');
    char *realLast = last + 1;
    std::cout << "Destination is: " << realLast<<", IP is: "<<L3AddressResolver().resolve(realLast);//=====
    strcpy(temp,realLast);
    strtok(temp,"[");
    strcpy(numberOfDestNode, strtok(NULL, "]"));
    int realDestNumber = std::stoi(numberOfDestNode);
    recArray[realDestNumber]++;
    std::cout<<", Number of destination is: "<<realDestNumber<<std::endl;//=================
}
```

The code runs very nicely and fast but when this function is called, the execution goes significantly slow. 
This code is a part of a simulation project in Omnet++ and this function is called every time when a node sends a message to another. So consider if there are 1000 nodes, this function will be called 1000 times.
I might be doing something unneeded here.

Comment: Resolving and blocking isn't a fantastic plan.  Ideally you'd start the resolve; and then when the resolve is complete you'd get a callback. Can't say if L3AddressResolver supports that feature already; but if it does; that's what you want to be using

Comment: This is very very obvious, but if this is your real code and you want it to run fast, can you remove or comment out the `cout` statements? After that you could avoid at least some of the string copying, but you should really profile before making more changes.

Comment: `std::cout` can very slow, depending what it's outputting to (like a terminal). Can you store the results in memory to be printed later?

Comment: @Useless cout statements are just for making sure results are generated. I tried commenting them. '

Comment: @Galik yes tried. removing cout statements don't help

Comment: If removing both the `cout` statements doesn't affect time at all, something is _tremendously_ slow. Anyway, the insight has to be that you need to measure and learn to profile.

Comment: How slow is slow, in exact numbers? That's quite crucial information when trying to understand the problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The code may be slightly optimized:

- The `L3Address` class has the convenient method `operator<<`, so the use of `L3AddressResolver().resolve(realLast)` is unnecessary ([INET API).](https://omnetpp.org/doc/inet/api-current/doxy/classinet_1_1_l3_address.html)
- One should avoid using `cout` for logging ([OMNeT++ Manual](https://omnetpp.org/doc/omnetpp/manual/#sec:sim-lib:log-statements)). `EV` should be used instead of `cout`.
- To obtain an index of a module in vector of modules one can use `getIndex()` method from `cModule` class.

Presented code may be rewritten into the following one:

```
void UDPBasicApp::incrementReceiveCounter(const L3Address& dest) {       
  cModule *destHost = L3AddressResolver().findHostWithAddress(dest);
  if (destHost) {
        int realDestNumber = destHost->getIndex();
        recArray[realDestNumber]++;
        EV << "Destination is: " << destHost->getName() <<", IP is: "
           << dest << ", Number of destination is: "
           << realDestNumber << std::endl;
   }
}
```

To increase the speed of the simulation you should consider:

1. Building the simulation in release mode.
2. Running the simulation in Cmdenv mode.

Comment: Is `toIPv4()` really equivalent? If it is, it does the same work as the existing code; if it's not, you broke the code!

Comment: The `toIPv4()` is fully equivalent provided that IPv4 is used in the network. The more generic solution is to print just an `L3Address` object because its `operator<<` checks the type of address. I have improved my answer.

Comment: Is there some reason you're not recommending the use of the statistics modules that come with OMNeT++ instead of cout/EV logging? I would expect that to be way more efficient than cout/EV logging.

Comment: @RensvanderHeijden Code in my answer does exactly the same as the code in the question. I don't know what is the intension of the logging to console in the original code, so I cannot propose another solution.

Comment: An overdue thank you. You answered the question plus added some more understanding of omnet to my knowledge. Cheers

Answer (score 4):

If you're sending 1000 messages to the *same* destination, then you are performing 999 unnecessary name lookups. Each of those may require a roundtrip to a DNS server on your network. That's very inefficient.

You should resolve the name *once*, the first time you need to contact a particular destination. Cache it for next time. A good resolver will tell you how long it's safe to cache it for. An even better resolver will use the OS to do the resolution (and caching) for you, but even if you have one of those you are still making unnecessary calls to the OS.

It is not possible to give more details without a [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) or, at least, some idea of what `L3AddressResolver` precisely does.

However, if each time the destination is different, there's really not much you can do. You need to allow time for the lookup to happen. The best you can do is to perform it asynchronously so that more than one lookup can happen at the same time.

Depending on how your application is structured, and depending on what your requirements are, and if you know in advance what they'll be, you may want to consider looking up all the names ahead of time. Then you still spend the same amount of time, but in a different place (and potentially *asynchronously* while other functions are taking place); then *this* particular function will be very fast. Only you can say whether that'll be helpful.

Comment: One might argue that `L3AddressResolver` may already do all this, and that's theoretically true, but I think the OP's results speak for themselves (and, therefore, speak to the contary).

Comment: each time the destination is randomly generated. It is not always the same. I know what you mean but it's different every time it is called

Comment: L3AddressResolver resolves the ip of a node from its name or the other way around

Comment: @Saad: _"L3AddressResolver resolves the ip of a node from its name or the other way around"_ Yes, I got that bit. The question is _how_ does it accomplish that.

Comment: @Saad: _"it's different every time it is called"_ Then there's not much you can do.

Comment: Not sure what `L3AddressResolver` directly translates to. But if it's not POD, you might squeeze some speed out by passing it via reference instead of value.

Comment: @M4rc: Passing it from where?

Comment: Depending on where the object is allocated and it's lifetime, as a parameter.

Comment: @M4rc: It is not a parameter in the code we've been shown.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit I should have been more clear -- the `dest` parameter of the `L3AddressResolver` type.

Comment: @M4rc: Ah, you mean the `dest` parameter of `L3Address` type. Then yes I agree, to a point - compared to the cost of name resolution it'll likely be very small, but there doesn't seem a reason to pass that by value.

Comment: The question wasn't very clear, but [L3AddressResolver](https://github.com/inet-framework/inet/blob/master/src/inet/networklayer/common/L3AddressResolver.cc#L497) basically translates IP addresses to OMNeT++ nodes (which are simulated instances of real machines, e.g., servers or nodes in an ad-hoc network). This is a step necessary only because the simulation back-end doesn't work with IP addresses.